Issue with pagination on my PyCharm script
I have been trying to use scrape this website (https://www.datacenters.com/locations/united-states/virginia) and the pagination is not working. I have tried all sorts of things but can't get it to work. it will only scrape the first page. Can anyone help? I am using pycharm.
Sure, here's the exact code you provided:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# Base URL of the website
base_url = 'https://www.datacenters.com'
# URL of the main webpage to scrape
main_url = f'{base_url}/locations/united-states/virginia'

def get_data_from_page(url, writer):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        location_tiles = soup.find_all('div', class_='LocationTile__details__sXkB0')
        
        if not location_tiles:
            print(f"No location tiles found on {url}")
        
        for tile in location_tiles:
            name = tile.find('div', class_='LocationTile__name__NrDKr').text
            address = tile.find('div', class_='LocationTile__address__Utj30').text
            
            parent_anchor = tile.find_parent('a', href=True)
            if parent_anchor:
                relative_link = parent_anchor['href']
                link = f'{base_url}{relative_link}'
                
                detail_response = requests.get(link)
                if detail_response.status_code == 200:
                    detail_soup = BeautifulSoup(detail_response.content, 'html.parser')
                    
                    power_div = detail_soup.find('div', id='power')
                    power = power_div.find('strong').text.strip() if power_div else 'N/A'
                    
                    sqf_div = detail_soup.find('div', id='statInfo')
                    sqf = sqf_div.find('strong').text.strip() if sqf_div else 'N/A'
                    
                    # Write the data to the CSV file
                    writer.writerow([name, address, power, sqf, link])
                    print(f"Scraped data for {name}")
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to retrieve details from {link}. Status code: {detail_response.status_code}")
            else:
                print(f"No link found for {name}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve the webpage. Status code: {response.status_code}")

# Open a CSV file to write the data
with open('datacenters.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    # Write the header row
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Address', 'Power', 'SQF', 'Link'])
    
    # Start with the first page
    page_url = main_url
    while True:
        print(f"Scraping page: {page_url}")
        get_data_from_page(page_url, writer)
        
        # Check if there is a next page link
        response = requests.get(page_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        next_page_button = soup.find('button', class_='Control__control__ijHLR Pagination__pageItem__NsQSw Pagination__symbol__KHv6r')
        if next_page_button and not 'Pagination__disabled__FbUC6' in next_page_button['class']:
            next_page_button.click()
            next_page_link_tag = soup.find('a', href=True)
            if next_page_link_tag:
                next_page_link = next_page_link_tag['href']
                page_url = f"{base_url}{next_page_link}"
                print(f"Next page link found: {page_url}")
            else:
                print("Next page link not found.")
                break
        else:
            print("No more pages.")
            break

Feel free to ask if you need any further assistance or modifications!
I have tried multiple configurations but I am consistently getting errors indicating there is no next button.

The page appears to implement pagination using an API with endpoint locations https://www.datacenters.com/api/v1/locations, and for Virginia using values https://www.datacenters.com/api/v1/locations?page=7&query=&country_id=234&state_id=3173.
The page also appears to use React and Rails components, which makes it difficult to get any working link to the next button functionality. So I used bs4 to find the state's JSON data and pass the info to your page method.
The below code seems to work closest to what you already have.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import json

# Base URL of the website
base_url = 'https://www.datacenters.com'
# URL of the main webpage to scrape
main_url = f'{base_url}/locations/united-states/virginia'

def get_data_from_page(relative_link, name, address, writer):
    link = f'{base_url}{relative_link}'
    detail_response = requests.get(link)

    if detail_response.status_code == 200:
        detail_soup = BeautifulSoup(detail_response.content,
                                    'html.parser')

        power_div = detail_soup.find('div', id='power')
        power = power_div.find(
            'strong').text.strip() if power_div else 'N/A'

        sqf_div = detail_soup.find('div', id='statInfo')
        sqf = sqf_div.find(
            'strong').text.strip() if sqf_div else 'N/A'

        # Write the data to the CSV file
        writer.writerow([name, address, power, sqf, link])
        print(f"Scraped data for {name}")


# Open a CSV file to write the data
with open('datacenters.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    # Write the header row
    writer. writerow(['Name', 'Address', 'Power', 'SQF', 'Link'])

    # Start with the first page
    page_url = main_url

    print(f"Scraping page: {page_url}")
    response = requests.get(main_url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        state_tag = soup.find('script',
                              attrs={'class': 'js-react-on-rails-component',
                                     'data-component-name': 'StateShow'})

        state_json_data = json.loads(state_tag.text)
        for i, location in enumerate(state_json_data['show']['mapLocations'], 1):
            print(f'{i}', end=' ')
            get_data_from_page(location['url'], location['name'],
                               location['fullAddress'], writer)

